# Download File from server that uses Icefaces form based authentication

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I am a newbie to ICEfaces and i have a requirement where i need to download a document from a given url (http://ipaddress/formexec?objectid=201).

This URL uses a **form based authentication** that is deployed through ICEFaces.

i tracked the request of this URL and i get the following line:

```
&ice.submit.partial=false&ice.event.target=loginForm%3Aj_id33&ice.event.captured=loginForm%3Aj_id33
```

Is there any libraries or code to download the document by successfully passing the **username and password.**

Comment: To be sure: with form based authentication you mean to say that you're using `j_security_check` and not a homegrown one?

Comment: yes... it is using j_security_check and i tried a code to download a document from sites.google.com that once again uses a form based authentication, it was working. Only for this site it was not working The request from the browser will be POST /Site/block/send-receive-updates

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the `jsessionid` from the `Set-Cookie` response header and append it as URL attribute to the subsequent requests as `http://example.com/path/page.jsf;jsessionid=XXX`.

Here's a kickoff example with help of "plain vanilla" [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html):

```
// Prepare stuff.
String loginurl = "http://example.com/login";
String username = "itsme";
String password = "youneverguess";
URLConnection connection = null;
InputStream response = null;

// First get jsessionid (do as if you're just opening the login page).
connection = new URL(loginurl).openConnection();
response = connection.getInputStream(); // This will actually send the request.
String cookie = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
String jsessionid = cookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[1]; // This assumes JSESSIONID is first field (normal case), you may need to change/finetune it.
String jsessionidurl = ";jsessionid=" + jsessionid;
response.close(); // We're only interested in response header. Ignore the response body.

// Now do login.
String authurl = loginurl + "/j_security_check" + jsessionidurl;
connection = new URL(authurl).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST method.
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("j_username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8")
          + "&j_password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8"));
writer.close();
response = connection.getInputStream(); // This will actually send the request.
response.close();

// Now you can do any requests in the restricted area using jsessionid. E.g.
String downloadurl = "http://example.com/download/file.ext" + jsessionidurl;
InputStream download = new URL(downloadurl).openStream();
// ...
```

To achieve the same with less bloated code, consider [Apache Commons HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Form based auth is not much different from other requests. All you have to do is to submit an a request to the auth form providing required parameters, such as user and password and in some cases additional token that you would have to get from the source page. Then you need to get cookies from the auth response or session id parameter and copy them to your next request that will fetch the data.